# Site doesn't work with WWW at the start of the address

Tags: ee2

We're using EE and I'm also using the Focus Lab Multi Environment Config file on one of our sites and for some reason our site won't work with WWW at the start of the address.

I have confirmed with the hosting provider that everything is correct from their end, but am confused as to where to move from here.

Is there something in the config file that should be modified to make this work again?

Very new to the Focus Lab Config file.

Comment: What hosting provider are you with? Can you show us your .htaccess file contents?

Comment: Sounds like an .htaccess error, can you show the .htaccess file or the parts related to EE.

Comment: Hi Guys. I actually don't have a .htaccess file at root. Do I need one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Focus Lab Config `config.env.php` file, you might need to make sure that both www and non www are specified in the `switch` statement.

```
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
  case 'website.com' :
  case 'www.website.com' :
    define('ENV', 'prod');
    define('ENV_FULL', 'Production');
    define('ENV_DEBUG', FALSE);
  break;

  ...
}
```

But saying that, you should really only be using one or the other. Being able to access the site using www and non-www will lead to duplicate content on Google. Not good.

Your htaccess needs to have something like this to force the removal of www.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteBase /  
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

There are many different ways to do it and you can find plenty of resources on how to do it.
 [Here's one on how to force www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916222/htaccess-how-to-force-www-in-a-generic-way).

Comment: Yup... That did it, thanks for your help. I can't be the only one who has run into this. Is there a better way. I have 2 sites running the focus Lab config file and it's doing the same thing on both. I don't want to have duplicat content problems. Any thoughts?

Comment: I just tried your suggestion on the 2nd site and it doesn't seem to work. I was great on the first though. Very confused. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you use htaccess to force www or non-www, you will avoid this problem completely in the first place.

Comment: You can simplify the code even more by removing the WWW from the switch statement. `switch (str_replace('www.', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))`. This will ensure you only have to define the case once, and it works with all the environments.

Comment: Thanks guys. That fixed my issues. Very much appreciated.